# How can I modify my lm object to contain robust standard errors?

Tags: r, regression, lm

I'm aware of packages in R (e.g. `sandwich`) which take an `lm` object and create robust standard errors on the summary. What I need is to manipulate my `lm` object so that it has robust standard errors (not just changing the summary of the `lm`). Ultimately, I want to plot an interaction from my (`lm`) model using the effects package but the input for effect needs to be an `lm`.

All the manipulations I've tried only change the `summary.lm()` output and not the `lm` model itself.

How can I call an `lm` object, calculate the robust standard errors, and maintain the variable as an `lm` object?

Basically, I'm trying to replicate the `marginsplot` function in Stata after running an OLS model with robust standard errors.

Comment: Would the `rlm` function in the package `MASS` work? It performs robust regression using M- or MM-estimation. It returns an object inheriting from the class "lm".

Comment: Generally questioners are expected to produce an example to be used for purposes of illustration that can be cut and pasted into a console session running the language of choice. These are referred to as [MCVE]. If you need advice about what misconception(s) your code might illustrate, then you also need to post attempted code and error messages.

Comment: If I understand your question, your actual goal is to generate the equivalent of a Stata marginsplot in R from a model that has robust standard errors. One way might be to kludge together an `lm` summary object with robust standard errors from another function, but I'd bet there are other, perhaps easier, ways. If you provide a reproducible example, it will make it much easier to help you, and we'll be able to provide code tailored to your problem.